# List of $4$-valent planar graphs

Tags: graph-theory, big-list

May I know where I can find a complete list of $4$-valent planer graphs with $n$ vertices for relatively small value of $n$?

Comment: Look at a list of knots and links ... treat the crossings as verticies http://katlas.math.toronto.edu/wiki/The_Rolfsen_Knot_Table

Comment: Thanks @DonaldSplutterwit! Does the list of knots and links, after regarding overcrossings and undercrossings as vertices, gives us the complete list of $4$-valent planer graphs?

Comment: Every planar $4$-valent graph can be turned into an alternating knot or link. If it is alternating then number of crossing cannot be decreased by a sequence or Riedermeister moves. Mild note of caution ... these lists will only contain prime knots and not their sums.

Comment: Thanks @DonaldSplutterwit! Do you happen to know a reference for the conclusion mentioned above?

Comment: I have not studied knot theory for about $20$ years, so I am knot best placed to give you a good reference. But if you google "knot theory lecture notes" you will find lots of relevant stuff.

Comment: Sure. Thank you again for your time! @DonaldSplutterwit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your value of $n$ is small, but not so small that you want to go through a list of knots and links by and, an alternative is `plantri`: http://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/~bdm/plantri/.

This is a C program that will generate a list of planar graphs with certain properties, depending on the input. In your case, supposing you want graphs on $12$ vertices, you could use

```
plantri -p -m4 -c1 -e24 12
```

where `-p` asks for general planar simple graphs, `-m4` asks for graphs with minimum degree $4$, `-c1` asks for graphs with minimum connectivity $1$ (connected graphs), `-e24` asks for graphs with $24$ edges (together with the minimum degree condition, this implies that the graph is $4$-regular), and `12` asks for $12$-vertex graphs.

(In general, for $n$-vertex graphs, you will want the `-e` parameter to be $2n$.)

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I appreciate it a lot.